# How to Fix SSL Error on Windows 10 for Discord Bot

Tags: python, ssl, bots, discord

I have a Discord bot I've been running on a Windows 10 VM for several months, and yesterday it stopped working with the following error:

```
raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443
 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer cerificate (_ssl.c:1108)')]
```

The only fix I've found online is for MacOS which involves running a .command file.

Note: The bot can be run on my main PC, but it will not run on my secondary PC or any of my VMs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have this same exact symptom. Perhaps Discord changed something on their end which has broken the python discord module ?

Comment: try this may be https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/gne6b9/discord_bot_ssl_error_on_windows_10/

Answer (score 1):

I opened discordapp.com in my browser and it suddenly worked.